# Can you skip to the END block of a powershell advance function?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

In a sample function like

```
function get-foo
{ 
    param ($name)
    BEGIN {#I'm checking for something like $name being true/false}
    PROCESS {#If $name is true I'll do something otherwise I want 
             to skip to END}
    END {#last stuff}
}
```

Is there an actually cmdlet to skip to the end block or would I just have to make a if statement that checks a variable and wrap that around the inside of my proces block? Like so,

```
function get-foo
    { 
        param ($name)
        BEGIN {#I'm checking for something like $name being true/false}
        PROCESS {If ($name) {#If $name is true I'll do something otherwise I want to skip to END} }
        END {#last stuff}
    }
```

Comment: You can't wrap anything around the process block. And no, AFAIK there's no way to "skip" to the end block. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I updated the original post. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: The primary purpose of `BEGIN`, `PROCESS`, and `END` is to handle piped data.  Is it that you want to bail out of the pipeline early?  I am not sure if it is possible to do that.  `Process` will still be invoked once for every item in the pipeline, even if you are just skipping the body of the script block.  If you are not piping `$name` to `get-foo` then I do not think `BEGIN`, `PROCESS`, and `END` have any value here and you can just get rid of them.  If you tell us what you are ultimately trying to achieve we may be able to recommend something.